# Calculate Number of years between dates in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to calculate the number of **complete** years between two dates in sql. The query I am using currently to calculate is

```
--Date1 > Date2
CASE
WHEN YEAR(Date1) = YEAR(Date2)
    THEN DATEDIFF(year, Date2, Date1)
WHEN YEAR(Date1) > YEAR(Date2) 
        AND MONTH(Date1) >= MONTH(Date2)
        AND DAY(Date1) >= DAY(Date2)
    THEN DATEDIFF(year, Date2, Date1)
ELSE
    DATEDIFF(year, Date2, Date1) - 1
```

However I need to tweak it somehow so that it considers the time between 1/5/2011 and 30/4/2012 as 1 complete year.

Comment: Captain Obvious to the rescue: if `YEAR(Date1) = YEAR(Date2)`, then 0 complete years went by - no need to subtract. (Unless it's Jan 1st to Dec 31st, in which case no need to subtract either.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add one day to `Date2` before you compare it:

```
dateadd(day, 1, Date2)
```

Comment: sometimes the simplest way is the easiest way :P

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to consider 1-year-less-a-day to be a full year, what about simply adding 1 day to your later date?  dateadd() should do it.

```
mysql> SELECT ADDDATE('2011-05-01', INTERVAL 1 DAY);
        -> '2011-05-02'
```

I don't *think* that would cause other erroneous calculations...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't totally accurate, but it's close:
It calculates the difference in days, divides by 365.25, then rounds down.

```
DECLARE @d1 datetime = '2000-01-01', @d2 datetime = GETDATE();
SELECT CAST(ROUND(DATEDIFF(DAY, @d1, @d2)/365.25, 0, 1) AS INT);
```